# KDevelop projects not recognizing standard headers

Tags: windows, cmake, include, mingw, kdevelop

I have a fresh MinGW installation at "C:\MinGW", and added "C:\MinGW\bin" to my user PATH.

I start a project with `-G "MinGW Makefiles"` as instructed.

However, KDevelop doesn't recognize `#include <iostream>` even though it is located in `C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++`.

I've tried adding MinGW\lib to my PATH, I've tried "\bin\", I've tried a semicolon before the path (that made the compiler fail, so I removed it).

KDevelop is STILL highlighting `<iostream>` and `using namespace std;` as implicitly-defined.

Compiling manually through the command line with g++ works fine.

Comment: So, without `SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS   "-IC:/MinGW/lib" )` the code doesn't even compile? Then there is something broken in your MinGW installation.

Comment: Just tested again, it does compile and work through KDevelop as well as manually, *without* the SET command. The syntax is still highlighted as unrecognized headers.